# Copy image to canvas without requesting the image again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I am dealing with a captcha image that regenerates everytime it is requested. I need a way of copying it without requesting it from its url again.
A good solution is best shown by right clicking an image and clicking the "copy image" option, only i need a programmatic solution that doesn't involve the user's help. So Chrome is able to copy the image without having to request it again. I need a way of doing that.

I have tried using javascript's document.execCommand("copy") but that proved to be tricky with a page that has multiple elements. Then, i read about canvas copying which can copy the pixels? of an image to a new canvas, i think that way maybe i will be able to copy the image from the new canvas without having to worry about triggering regeneration of the captcha again. The thing is i need to copy the image to a canvas but without having to request the image from the src again.

Any sort of solution will help as long as it can be implemented in an extension and can be automatically done with minimal user interaction.

Comment: why do you need the captcha images??

Comment: I have a made a java app that can read a captcha image and return the text within it. This isnt anything malicious, i'm building an automation process for my company's QA team

Comment: If you get the image and put it on the canvas it will be tainted, you will not be able to access the pixel data unless you have control of the server. To get the image, use XMLHttpRequest object to request the image from the server. unless its just an image then just create a Image and point the src at the captcha URL

Comment: So you're unit testing the captcha routine for **internal** QA purposes? Then your method might be way more complex than it needs to be. If the captcha is generated internally on the server-side, then, *during QA development only*, have the server make available the captcha text in addition to the captcha image. Of course, pull the testing code out when going gold.

Comment: Its not for internal purposes, the QA team needs to preform sanity checks in production environment as well

Comment: @Kaiido I did not say using AJAX would clean the data.

Comment: @Kaiido The QA story does not jell with me, too verbose. And in another post he says "...screenshots are not high enough quality..." to read (more like can't get a screenshot of what the client should not see) The OP wants pixel access to a 3rd party image, most likely to attempt access to a service under guise and without client knowledge

Comment: @Blindman67  i cant see a captcha? wtf are you talking about, if you cant help then dont, but dont come here making accusations. My team is currently using selenium to take screenshots of captcha images and supply them to my java app to read. the screenshots are not high enough quality so i need a way to copy the image, why is this so hard to believe? did you never hear of a company preforming QA tests on production environment??